# How can I get the Cloudflare server IP in logs while using mod_cloudflare?

Tags: apache, cloudflare

From what I can see, mod_cloudflare - https://github.com/cloudflare/mod_cloudflare - on Apache will simply replace the remote IP with the "correct" one (the users IP address replacing the Cloudflare server IP address that it came from at a TCP level), however, I require in my logs both the client IP address and the server IP address.

Is there any way to log this while using the standard mod_cloudflare module, and if not, what modifications would need to be made to mod_cloudflare to enable a new header that could be logged for this?

Answer (score 0):

That isn't something that mod_cloudflare will be able to help with.  But you might find some helpful information here:

http://www.techstacks.com/howto/log-client-ip-and-xforwardedfor-ip-in-apache.html

Comment: I don't think that link is useful, because mod_cloudflare specifically overwrites the standard remote IP before any of the standard LogFormat things take place.

Answer (score 0):

I have something like this `LogFormat` in my `httpd.conf`:

```
LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i (%h) %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" combined
```

In my particular environment this puts the `X-Forwarded-For` (real IP) in first and in brackets it will add the "proxy" ip(s).